# MySQL Select entries missing from another table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm attempting to get a list of values that don't exist in another table for a specific date.

Table Layouts:

```
table1 (TABLE)
 id INT(10)

table2 (TABLE)
 id INT(10)
 table1id INT(10)
 dateupdated DATETIME(19)
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a9fc/1)

Query that I thought would work that isn't.

```
SELECT t1.id FROM Table1 as t1
    JOIN Table2 as t2
    ON t1.id=t2.table1id
    WHERE date(t2.dateupdated) != DATE(NOW())
```

I'm expecting id 7 and 8 to come back from the above query, since they don't exist in Table2. But I'm getting no rows back.

Reversing the Query to match = DATE(NOW()) gives me the lines that do have matches

```
SELECT t1.id FROM Table1 as t1
JOIN Table2 as t2
ON t1.id=t2.table1id
WHERE date(t2.dateupdated) = DATE(NOW())
```

Response:

```
id
1
2
3
4
5
6
9
10
```

Any guidance would be appreciated, I'm still learning MySQL. But I'm missing something very simple here.

Comment: Try using a LEFT JOIN with NULL values in the right table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a9fc/11

```
SELECT t1.id FROM Table1 as t1
    LEFT JOIN Table2 as t2
    ON t1.id=t2.table1id
     AND date(t2.dateupdated) = DATE(NOW())
    WHERE t2.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Shouldn't `AND date(t2.dateupdated) = DATE(NOW())` be part of WHERE clause although I am not sure why the query is working in the SQL Fiddle.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Thank you! I'm going to go read up on LEFT JOINs to see where I was missing my logic. (I'll accept answer in 5 minutes when it allows me to)

Comment: @Maximus2012 it can be part of the where or the join since it's applying that filter table2 either way.

Comment: @AndrewWilson There are also other ways of doing this involving EXISTS and IN clauses as well that you can look into.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is always more than one way, another way is using the NOT IN operator with a subquery (since MySQL doesn't support MINUS).

```
SELECT t1.id FROM Table1 as t1
WHERE t1.id NOT IN
(SELECT t2.table1id FROM Table2 as t2
    WHERE date(t2.dateupdated) = DATE(NOW()))
```

For DBMS that do support MINUS, you could do:

```
SELECT t1.id FROM Table1 as t1
MINUS
SELECT t2.table1id FROM Table2 as t2
    WHERE date(t2.dateupdated) = DATE(NOW())
```

Comment: I actually tried that and the query took a very long time (10x the amount of the LEFT JOIN below)

Comment: @AndrewWilson Do you have an index on that field?

Comment: It shouldn't take any longer than the LEFT JOIN, atleast not a noticeably longer time.

Comment: In real example Table 1 has a numerical index, Table 2 has a UUID v4 index

Comment: @AndrewWilson You can use the EXPLAIN keyword before an SQL query to get your database server to tell you the execution plan it uses. This will tell you which one of our suggestions is the most efficient in your specific set up.

Comment: @AndrewWilson, to be honest though, if the LEFT JOIN works, then no need to worry more.  These are pretty similar in how they are executed, just different ways to get the end result.   I just thought I'd share another approach.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way that I prefer to do it:

```
SELECT id FROM Table1
    WHERE id not in (select table1id from Table2 where date(dateupdated) = date(NOW()))
```

Answer (score -1):

Learning mysql I found this invaluable reference: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Hope you find it useful!

Since the JOIN doesn't retrieve NULL rows, you have to use a LEFT or RIGHT JOIN to deal with empty ROWS.